# linux rename files in bulk using bash script or command line one liner

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-io

I have a list of for example 100 files with the naming convention

```
<date>_<Time>_XYZ.xml.abc
<date>_<Time>_XYZ.xml
<date>_<Time>_XYZ.csv
```

for example

```
20140730_025373_XYZ.xml
20140730_015233_XYZ.xml.ab
20140730_015233_XYZ.csv
```

Now I want to write  script which will remove anything between two underscores. for example in the above case

```
remove 015233 and change 20140730_015233_XYZ.xml.ab to 20140730_XYZ.xml.ab
remove 015233 and change 20140730_015233_XYZ.csv to 20140730_XYZ.csv
```

I have tried number of various options using rename, cut, mv but I am getting varied results, not the one which I expect.

Comment: Show us what you tried and how it failed.  That will make it a lot easier to help you because we see what exactly you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for FILE in *; do mv "$FILE" "${FILE/_*_/_}"; done
```

And more specific is

```
for FILE in *.xml *.xml.ab *.csv; do mv "$FILE" "${FILE/_*_/_}"; done
```

Further:

```
for FILE in *_*_*.xml *_*_*.xml.ab *_*_*.csv; do mv "$FILE" "${FILE/_*_/_}"; done
```

Comment: I am really grateful to you all, for your help. konsolebox, hek2mgl,Kalanidhi M.,Avinash Raj. Thanks very much. all solutions are elegant.

Comment: what if the file name is like 20140821_154933_ABC_VMG.csv.md5 and need to rename it to 20140821_ABC_VMG.csv.md5

Comment: Try `for FILE in *_*_*_*.csv.md5; do mv "$FILE" "${FILE/_*_/_}"; done`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use rename command if you want to rename files present inside the current directory,

```
rename 's/^([^_]*)_[^_]*(_.*)$/$1$2/g' *
```

Comment: Like that attempt (of using tools which are meant for that special purpose) +1 However, it is not said that files should be renamed having information from the question (I now realize)... Anyhow...

Comment: Oh, I now realized the headline. Missed that! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([^_]*\)_.*_\(.*\)/\1_\2/' files.list
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `cut` command

```
cut -d'_' -f1,3 filename
```

Comment: Probably the best solution!